# Исключить последний символ в событии

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть событие типа `$(".class").on("input", ...`

В нем есть условие,

```js
var balance = 10000;
$(".sumOut").on("input", function() {
  if ($.isNumeric(this.value)) {
    console.log(this.value); // Будет показывать те самые 150001 150002 и т.п., что ломает нижние условия..
    if (this.value.length >= 4) {

      if (this.value > 12e3) 
      {
        $('.sumOut').addClass('error_input');
        $('.error_text.s').text('Некорректная сумма');
        $('.error_text.s').fadeIn(350);
        $(this).val(12e3);


      } else if (this.value > balance) {
        $('.sumOut').addClass('error_input');
        $('.error_text.s').text('Недостаточно средств, поэтому установлена сумма равная вашему балансу');
        $('.error_text.s').fadeIn(350);
        $(this).val(balance);

      }

    }
  } else this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
})
```

```css
.error_text {
  color: red;
  display: none;
}

.error_input {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="sumOut">
<p class="error_text s"></p>
```

И все вроде бы хорошо, но если продолжать тыкать, то в поле ничего меняться не будет. Т.е будет число 15000, однако смотря в `console.log(this.value)` можно увидеть, как появляются числа 150001, 150005, 150008 и т.п (зависит от нажатой кнопки). Это ломает идущие ниже условия..

Как это пофиксить ?

Comment: воспроизводимый пример сделайте - чтоб потыкать можно было

Comment: @humster_spb добавил целиком участок кода

Comment: Не участок кода нужен, а воспроизводимый пример - с разметкой, в сниппете. Чтоб его можно было запустить и посмотреть.

Comment: @humster_spb Готово.

Comment: `Это ломает идущие ниже условия` - напишите человеческим языком, что это означает. Как вы написали, так и работает. В нашем понимании - ничего не сломано.

Comment: @NoSkill проще говоря, если вы потыкаете, то увидите, что на вход идут числа типа 120004, 120005 и т.п., что как бы идет в разрез с идущим ниже условием `this.value > balance` и `this.value > 15e4` . Не находите ? Т.к 12000 не удовлетворяет условию 12000 > 12000, а 120005 явно больше, чем 15е4..Вот и нужно сделать так, чтобы не было этой цифры в конце

Comment: @NoSkill пардон, опечатка. 12e3. Да и какая разница, я указал на саму проблему.

Comment: может вам надо убрать `else if`... Откуда мне известно какую логику вы хотите реализовать.

Comment: @NoSkill хм..Если введенное число больше установленного максимума, то ставим максимум в инпут. Второе условие - Если введенное число больше, чем есть у нас на балансе - ставим максимумом число баланса. А в итоге получается, что 6-ти  значное число срабатывает на 2 условия, хотя по сути вводим мы 5..или я не понимаю логику работы `on. input`

Comment: @NoSkill попробуйте потыкать сейчас. Сделал наглядно, что выполняется 2 условия, вместо одного..из за этих 6ти символов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var balance = 10000;
var maxamount = 12000;

  $(".sumOut").on("input", function() {

    $('.error_text.s').text('');
    $('.error_text.s').hide();

    if ($.isNumeric(this.value)) {
    
      if (this.value > maxamount) {
        $('.sumOut').addClass('error_input');
        $('.error_text.s').text('Некорректная сумма (максимум ' + maxamount + ')');
        $('.error_text.s').fadeIn(350);
        $(this).val(maxamount);
      } 

      if (this.value > balance) {
        $('.sumOut').addClass('error_input');
        $('.error_text.s').text('Недостаточно средств, поэтому установлена сумма равная вашему балансу');
        $('.error_text.s').fadeIn(350);
        $(this).val(balance);
      }
   
    } else {
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
    }
  });
```

```css
.error_text {
  color: red;
  display: none;
}

.error_input {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="sumOut">
<p class="error_text s"></p>
```

Comment: Спасибо..в else беда знач была, как я понял